# variable sent to modal is not displayed

Tags: javascript, php, variables, modal-dialog

I was advised to delete my previous question and ask it again in a better and more structured way. The problem is that when I try to visualize a variable in modal it does not show. I send it by POST with JS. I enclose sample code:

http://live.datatables.net/voreyapa/7/edit

After selecting one or more rows from the table in an array, I save only the names and then convert them to a string. Then with POST I send them to the same page and try to visualize them in

(paragraph) as follows:

```
<?php var_dump($_POST['variable']); ?>
```

But as you can see in the sample code I sent above after This Names: the names are not displayed.

Comment: what happens if you do `var_dump($_POST['variable'])`

Comment: I tried, again not visualized

Comment: but what happens if you do `var_dump($_POST['variable'])` .  You must get some output somewhere in the script. If i include it in a random php file i get this output on the screen `'Notice: Undefined index: variable in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/codewars/test.php on line 3
NULL`` for example

Comment: When using JSBin, never try to use `alert`, they disable it by doing `window.alert=function(){};`. Use the more appropriate `console.log`

Comment: `print_r ($ value);` this should not have a space between the dollar sign and the variable name

Comment: I changed print_r ... with var_dump($_POST['variable']) ;. and I removed "alert" but again the names are not displayed after the modal is opened